# Pushing column to next line with col-md-push-*

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following 6 building blocks:

```
[1][2] 
[3][4]
[5][6]
```

All blocks have a col-sm-6 class in one row.
But since block 3 exceeds bootstraps 12 columns structuur it will jump to the next line.
Perfect that's what I want.

The only thing is, I want to swap block 2 and 3.
But it only works for blocks on the same line.
So 1 and 2 can swap, but 2 and 3 not (in SM mode)

```
 <div class="container">
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">  
        <div class="well"> 1 </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6 col-md-4 col-md-push-0">
        <div class="well"> 2 </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6 col-md-4 col-md-pull-0">
        <div class="well"> 3 </div>
    </div>

    <div class="clearfix hidden-sm"></div>

    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="well"> 4 </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="well"> 5 </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="well"> 6 </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

It will create:

```
    [1]   [2]
 [3]   [4]
    [5][6]
```

See 
http://www.bootply.com/127062

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're right, there is no way to push down to the next line in **Bootstrap 3.x**.

But, if you think "mobile first", you would first create the `sm` layout, and then push/pull it accordingly for larger screens..

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">  
            <div class="well"> 1 </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-push-0 col-md-4 col-md-push-4">
            <div class="well"> 3 </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-0 col-md-4 col-md-pull-4">
            <div class="well"> 2 </div>
        </div>

        <div class="clearfix hidden-sm"></div>

        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="well"> 4 </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="well"> 5 </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="well"> 6 </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/127076

**Update Bootstrap 4.x**

Now in Bootstrap 4 Beta [it's possible to "push" or "pull" columns to the next "row"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25714852/change-the-order-of-col-12-columns-in-bootstrap-3-by-using-push-pull/43231588#43231588) using the flexbox ordering classes:

https://www.codeply.com/go/MELnKiqofA

Comment: Well in XS mode I want col-12 blocks [1][2][3][4][5][6] in SM mode col-6 blocks in order [1][3][4][5][2][6] and from MD mode and larger col-4 blocks in [1][3][4][2][6][5] order :) Mobile first approach, but very hard to realize