# responsive design more than 2 column use order bootstrap3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using bootstrap 3 I have some questions about push/pull with column ordering. Here's what I am after:
now(in large size)

```
    .          .         .                                 
l   .    c     .     r   .                    
    .          .         .
```

to (in small size)

```
  .                   .                                     
  .         c         .                       
  .                   . 

  .        .          .                               
  .    l   .   r      .
  .        .          .
```

help me please?

Comment: Do you have any HTML to show us? It helps to see what you have attempted.

Comment: html code like this:

    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
       <div class="col-lg-6"></div>
       <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
    </div>

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pushing column to next line with col-md-push-\*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22839869/pushing-column-to-next-line-with-col-md-push)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `col-xs-*` for the smallest display layout. Change `col-lg-*` to `col-sm-*` so that Bootstrap uses this style for all other display sizes.

Setting `col2` to `col-xs-12` will force the other elements to be on a new row.

By moving `col2` to be the first item, you can use `col-sm-push-*` & `col-sm-pull-*` to move it to the second position on larger display sizes.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-push-2">col2</div>      
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2 col-sm-pull-6">col1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">col3</div>
</div>
```

Using the [BootStrap Grid Options](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options).

Comment: this code push the first column (col-sm-2) up and center column and right column in blow of first column ,but i wanna center col move to up

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. I found the answer and have edited my answer to suit. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/22840840/1442771