# Twitter Bootstrap 3 - Swap columns on extra-small devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid-layout

I have two columns in Twitter bootstrap, they look like this:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
   <div class="post">
      Something here
   </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
   <div class="post">
      Something here
   </div>
</div>
```

It scales down to full-width perfectly when on xs resolution, but **I would like to swap those two columns with each other**, so that the second column in the code would be the first column displayed and the first column in the code would be the second column displayed.

I tried using `col-xs-pull-12` and `col-xs-push-12` but it gave me weird results, columns were absolutely off grid. **How can I swap them using bootstrap's classes?** I want this to happen only on xs resolution.

Comment: You can't use `col-*-push-#`/`col-*-pull-#` classes to achieve that. Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25714852/change-the-order-of-col-12-columns-in-bootstrap-3-by-using-push-pull/25715035?s=20|3.2695#25715035 Also if supporting IE9- is not a concern, you could use *flexbox layout* and use `order` property.

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate post, I composed a vague search phrase, that's why I didn't see the question posted before mine. I suppose I should delete the question now.

Comment: No worries.. it's okay. Better not to delete the question as the others may find this from the result of search engines.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use `pull` and `push` on the right way .... That is for the larger devices:

1. Change the order of your markup exact the same you want on Mobile -- **Mobile First**
2. Add `push` and `pull` to change the order on larger devices

   ```
   <div class="col-md-8 col-md-push-4 col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="post">
         Something here Now
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4 col-md-pull-8 col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6 col-xs-12">
      <div class="post">
         Something here 
      </div>
   </div>
   ```

Check this **[BottplyDemo](http://www.bootply.com/diADuDXRqd)**