# Bootstrap 3 change fullwidth column order

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

One of our designers has created a layout where the footer content order changes from desktop to mobile. I'm using bootstrap and would like to do it as simply as possible. I believe the following is the correct markup but it doesn't seem to work for full width columns?

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-sm-push-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <p>Ooo content</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-sm-pull-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <p>Ooo more content</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/rwydcepc/

The aim of the above is to switch the top column with the bottom column when the `sm` is applied. This doesn't seem to happen though and everything screws up?

Is there another way to do this using bootstrap or with some simple additional css, ideally I'd like to **avoid duplicate content** and showing / hiding or relying on Javascript.

There is a similar question here but it doesn't answer the question: [Change the order of col-*-12 columns in Bootstrap 3 by using push/pull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25714852/change-the-order-of-col-12-columns-in-bootstrap-3-by-using-push-pull)

Comment: Create some css like .small-hidden and .small-show add two divs add the top that you want to toggle and two at the bottom. now the top ones and bottom ones will switch. you can use @media screen and (max-width: 720px)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is already a solution using [**Bootstrap reordering**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering) but not for 100% width columns, the below solution uses `Flexbox` method.

```css
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .reorder .row {
    display: flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .reorder .row .item1 {
    order: 2;
  }
  .reorder .row .item2 {
    order: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container reorder">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 item1">

      <p>Ooo content</p>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 item2">

      <p>Ooo more content</p>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works great, doesn't work for older browsers but guess I can use some JS as a fallback.

Comment: Yes. But Flexbox is for future usage :)

Comment: Also the bootstrap reordering doesn't work on columns with a width of 12/12