# bootstrap pulling/pushing 12 columns not working properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to have 2 columns inverted in middle (up) resolutions.

Here is my code on **[bootply](http://www.bootply.com/5LomVrt5AC)** that you can see here as well:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div style="border:1px solid red;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-md-push-12"><div style="background:yellow;">in xs this first</div></div>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-md-pull-12"><div style="background:orange;">in xs this after</div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, in xs screen, the order is the one written on screen.

What I wanted is that on bigger resolutions, the order should be inverted. Even if I push/pull a number of 12 columns (to have them inverted), the result is what you see.

Do you have any suggestion?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If your interested in doing without bootstrap than here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/23b9fL9w/1/)

You can call any classes and use wisely with Media Queries

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child-1">
        <p>First</p>
    </div>
    <div class="child-2">
        <p>Second</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent{
  display:table;
  width: 100%;
}

.parent .child-1{
  display: table-footer-group;
  background:yellow;
}

.parent .child-2{
  display: table-header-group;
  background:green;
}
```

Comment: You can find more solution on bootstrap full-width column pull-push here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25714852/change-the-order-of-col-12-columns-in-bootstrap-3-by-using-push-pull

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle. I ended up with a "poor-man" solution. I duplicated the div I want to move up/down and assigned a visibility class for XS / MD. That made the trick rapidly. Still I cannot figure out how come the push/pull thing doesn't work with col-*-12 divs.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstarp pulling pushing need proper column number like below

```
div style="border: solid 1px red">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9 col-md-push-3">.col-md-9 .col-md-push-3</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-md-pull-9">.col-md-3 .col-md-pull-9</div>
</div>
</div>
```

[Refer here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering)

Comment: so basically, if I want to push/pull col-*-12 , that cannot be done. Right?

Answer (score 0):

It's not really possible to reverse full-width (12) columns using Bootstrap push pull class. You'd have to use the responsive utility classes which requires duplicate content.

Or, use a CSS media query and transform to reverse the order on xs...

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .row.switch-xs {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    direction: rtl;
  }

  .row.switch-xs > [class^="col-"] {
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
    direction: ltr;
  }
}
```

Demo of both methods: http://bootply.com/nT8kUqB6d8

### Update 2017

**Now it's possible to reverse order of full-width columns on XS.**

For Bootstrap 4, no extra CSS is necessary for this. Simply use the flexbox ordering classes to "pull up" the 2nd div on `xs` screens:

```
   <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div style="background:orange;">last on xs</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 flex-first flex-md-unordered">
            <div style="background:yellow;">first on xs (pull me up)</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

http://codeply.com/go/NV4mTbRKpC