# bootstrap pull and push column

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I have read many topics here on stackoverflow regarding this question. I have read and used the solutions provided here, however! for some reason this stuff just doesn't work with me. I get a completely blank page.

The idea is to get primary button above the default button on extra small devices. For some reason i am completely blank even on md and sm devices.

Would appreciate help. Thank you

```
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-xs-push-12">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Button</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-xs-pull-12">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Button</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swap the positions of grids which are side by side to top and bottom using bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41096317/swap-the-positions-of-grids-which-are-side-by-side-to-top-and-bottom-using-boots)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot use the push/pull method on col-*-12 because of the way push/pull works.  So a solution that works very well is to have the order correct for mobile and then use the push/pull method on larger screen sizes like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-push-6">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Button</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-pull-6">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Button</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is a working codepen: http://codepen.io/egerrard/pen/NdqpXZ?

FYI, you are also only using `md` and `xs` column notations but you mention you only want this functionality for `xs` screen sizes.  If that is the case you need to change your `md` columns to `sm`.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to think "mobile-first". Create the markup for the smallest device layout first, and then adjust it using push/pull for larger screens. The `col-xs-12` is not necessary since the columns stack automatically on `xs` widths.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-6">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Button</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-pull-6">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Button</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://codeply.com/go/aUME1OcT0S

Update: As of Bootstrap 4, it's possible to re-order 12 unit columns: [bootstrap pulling/pushing 12 columns not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36442593/bootstrap-pulling-pushing-12-columns-not-working-properly)

Comment: Which Bootstrap version was this? In Bootstrap 4 nothing named like "`col-md-push-6`" can be found.

Comment: @Top-Master 5 years ago was Bootstrap 3, early Bootstrap 4. OFC Bootstrap 3 does have `col-md-push-6`