# Column ordering in Bootstrap 4 with push/pull and col-md-12

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I've two columns with the class `col-md-12` each.

In desktop view they should display like:

```
Col **1** 
Col **2**
```

In the mobile view the should display like this:

```
Col **2**
Col **1**
```

Is this even possible with the column ordering of Bootstrap?

My current code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-push-12 col-md-12">
        Col 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-pull-12 col-md-12">
        Col 2
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You've missed your base column code... `col-xs-12`

Comment: still doesn't work.. the cols are way too far left/right :(

Comment: That's because it's 100% width. See other question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25714852/3739498

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### UPDATE (FEB 2018) - v4+

Now that bootstrap has been released, you can achieved that using [**`order`**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#order-classes) utility classes as you were able to do it in beta version (see old update below),  with the difference that they've added these 3 new classes:

```css
.order-first {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 0;
  -ms-flex-order: -1;
  order: -1;
}

.order-last {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 14;
  -ms-flex-order: 13;
  order: 13;
}

.order-0 {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;
  -ms-flex-order: 0;
  order: 0;
}
```

---

#### Snippet

```css
.p-2 {
  background: red;
  border: white 5px solid
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="d-flex flex-column">
  <div class="p-2">1</div>
  <div class="p-2 order-first order-lg-2">2</div>
</div>
```

---

#### OLD UPDATE (OCT 2017) - v4.0.0 beta

With the release of beta version you can do this using flexbox utilities from bootstrap, such as [flex-order](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#flex-order)

(see answer from @ZimSystem - to see solution with alpha version)

```css
.p-2 {
  background: red;
  border: white 5px solid
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="d-flex flex-column">
  <div class="p-2">1</div>
  <div class="p-2 order-1 order-lg-2">2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but that's not working for full width columns right?

Comment: but it's side by side not full width

Comment: did this fix your issue?

Comment: @dippas Good 10/2017 update - didn't even realize those `order-x` utilities existed, very helpful

Answer (score 25):

**Update 2021 - Bootstrap 5 beta**

The `order-*` classed work the same way...

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            Col 1
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 order-first order-md-0">
            Col 2
        </div>
    </div>
```

[**Demo Bootstrap 5**](https://codeply.com/p/HZsKd3i3gR)

**Update 2019 - Bootstrap 4.3+**

Now full width, 12 unit `col-*-12` columns can be reversed using **flexbox** ordering.

In older Bootstrap 4 alpha and beta versions the ordering utils were `flex-*`...

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        Col 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 flex-first flex-md-unordered">
        Col 2
    </div>
</div>
```

[Demo Bootstrap 4 Alpha](https://www.codeply.com/go/YGjPnYwEUB)

As of **Bootstrap 4.0.0** the ordering utils are `order-*`...

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        Col 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 order-first order-md-2">
        Col 2
    </div>
</div>
```

[**Demo Bootstrap 4.1.0**](https://www.codeply.com/go/ic7sbXUFZ7)

See the docs at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#order-classes

Comment: This should definitely be the preferred answer now, since it doesn't rely on any external CSS rules, etc.

Comment: This needs to be the preferred answer now.

Comment: @kevlarr and Routhinator Hey guys I just updated my answer above with version of beta release.

Comment: @zimSystem the beta version already let you use `order-` utility classes, check my answer with october update and/or the CSS from beta version, they've updated this utility ;)

Comment: Dude.  What is the deal for us folks who aren't constantly using Bootstrap.  Why they make such a naming change.  This was painful to find.  Appreciate the post.

Answer (score 3):

One way around this is to make two versions of Col 2 and put one above Col 1 and one below it. Then use the [responsive utilities](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) to hide and show accordingly.

Comment: hmm, seems a bit "dirty"

Comment: It IS a bit dirty, but when we're discussing full-width columns it's one of the better options.  If you were using smaller grids we could rely on `col-*-push-*` and `col-*-pull-*` to achieve your desired results.

Comment: If you want to get really crazy with it, you can use jQuery and [clone it](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) and insert it before Col 1 on a `$(window).resize()` handler.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `flexbox`, then you can use media queries to change the order:

```
.row {
  /* Setup Flexbox */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  /* Reverse Column Order */
  -webkit-flex-flow: column-reverse;
  flex-flow: column-reverse;
}
```

### **[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/makshh/pen/KrvkdR)**

or (default order on mobiles and tablets, reverse on desktop):

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .row {
    /* Setup Flexbox */
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    /* Reverse Column Order */
    -webkit-flex-flow: column-reverse;
    flex-flow: column-reverse;
  }
}
```

### [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/makshh/pen/rLzpLq)

Comment: thanks, but I want a differnt order in mobile and desktop

Comment: I know, you can use media queries, I'll give you an example.

Comment: could be an option, if there is no solution with der column ordering