# Ordering Bootstrap divs

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

Having trouble with Bootstrap where I have two divs: (A) as col-lg-6 & (B) as col-lg-6 on a large device.

**will render: (A)(B)**

I am looking to display switch the order of the divs on a mobile or small device? col-sm-12

**will render: (B)
               (A)** *(to display on top of each other)

```
<section class="about-page">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row mineral_padding">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 order-1 wow fadeInLeft">
                <div class="about_us mineral_margin">
                    <div class="about_slide">
                        <div>
                            <h5>A
                            </h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 order-12 wow fadeInRight">B</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

I am using Bootstrap v4.0.0-alpha.6 (no going back here)

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, this question has been [answered before here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37814508/column-ordering-in-bootstrap-4) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38247873/column-ordering-in-bootstrap-4-with-push-pull-and-col-md-12).

In **Bootstrap 4 alpha.6** the ordering classes were `flex-*`, so it would be:

```
<section class="about-page">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row mineral_padding">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 flex-last flex-lg-first wow fadeInLeft">
                <div class="about_us mineral_margin">
                    <div class="about_slide">
                        <div>
                            <h5>A
                            </h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 wow fadeInRight">B</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/ajPR2ByFVM

As of 4.0 beta, the classes changed to order-* so instead you'd use `order-lg-first order-last` on the "A" div.

Comment: Thank you this worked.. Sorry for a duplicate question I didnt find what I was looking for before I posted my q.

Answer (score 0):

Use `order-lg-1 order-sm-0` on B
Use `order-lg-0 order-sm-1` on A
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#order

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section class="about-page">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row mineral_padding">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 order-lg-0 order-sm-1 wow fadeInLeft">
                <div class="about_us mineral_margin">
                    <div class="about_slide">
                        <div>
                            <h5>A
                            </h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 order-lg-1 order-sm-0 wow fadeInRight">B</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```